# Module not found error when adding Cypress command to husky pre-push

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, husky, git-husky

When running `cy run` (via `npm run test:e2e`) from the terminal it works just fine. The same command added to husky `pre-push` results in the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.3.1/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Contents/Resources/app/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:785:27)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

My `.husky/pre-push` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run test
npm run test:e2e
```

I cannot replicate the error via the terminal. Why is this error only happening with husky and how can I solve it?

- Platform: MacOS
- Node version: `16.14.2`
- Cypress version: `10.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using VSCode (I'm assuming you are as well), when trying to commit from VSCode UI.

When running from the command line using `git commit` - it works fine.

The answer may be an issue with Husky/VSCode similar to [Husky 4.x+ not working with Visual Studio Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196309/husky-4-x-not-working-with-visual-studio-git)